# Saving Image Files SQL database

Tags: android

Could someone please advise me on the best method for saving 
image files to the in-built SQL database built into Android.
I am trying to build an app that wil need to access a large
amount of pictures if possible. Please Advise...
I am usio
Many Thanks.

Comment: wouldn't be better to store pictures in device memory and in the database just a reference?

Comment: You can do that , but converting bitmap to bytes and then to String. Save this string to database get viseversa. Base64.java class can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in Android database is called SQLite3. You can insert and retrieve arbitrary binary data in database fields, you just need to make sure your `insert` statement correctly encodes the data as string literals. According to the [SQLite expression syntax](http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html), binary data can be written in a string literal as `X'...'` where the ... is a bunch of hex digits.